# How do you include bluetooth in a yocto linux system

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, embedded-linux, yocto, microchip

Does any know of any good instructions explaining how to implement bluetooth into a yocto build.

I've added bluetooth into the MACHINE variable within the machine.conf and bluez to CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL in the local.conf located in my build directory. After building a new image, bluetoothd won't start because this condition is not met ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth which is correct because that location doesn't exist on my system.

I'm new to yocto so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

So the /conf/bblayers has the following content:

```
  BBLAYERS ?= " \
     ${BSPDIR}/poky/meta \
     ${BSPDIR}/poky/meta-poky \
     ${BSPDIR}/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
     ${BSPDIR}/meta-atmel \
     ${BSPDIR}/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
     ${BSPDIR}/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
     ${BSPDIR}/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
     ${BSPDIR}/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
     ${BSPDIR}/meta-swupdate \
     ${BSPDIR}/meta-custom \
     ${BSPDIR}/meta-openembedded/meta-initramfs \
```

The local.conf contains:

```
    CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "\
      bluez5 \
      rpm \
      valgrind \
    "

    DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd bluetooth"
    DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED += "sysvinit"

    VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
    VURTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = "systemd-compat-units"
```

The .inc file in my custom layer contains:

```
#IMAGE_FEATURES += "ssh-server-openssh package-management"

IMAGE_INSTALL = "\
    packagegroup-core-boot \
    packagegroup-core-full-cmdline \    
    packagegroup-base-bluetooth  \
    kernel-modules \
    libgpiod \
    ntp \
    sqlite3 \
    openssl \
    mtd-utils \
    ${CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL} \
  "
    inherit core-image
```

The machine conf file contains:

```
MACHINE_FEATURES = "apm ext2 ext3 pcmcia usbhost usbgadget"
```

Running

```
bitbake -e packagegroup-base | grep ^ADD_BT
```

Returns

```
ADD_BT="packagegroup-base-bluetooth"
```

```
bitbake -e <image-name> | grep ^IMAGE_INSTALL=
```

Returns

```
IMAGE_INSTALL="    packagegroup-core-boot     packagegroup-core-full-cmdline     packagegroup-base-bluetooth      kernel-modules     libgpiod     ntp     sqlite3     openssl     mtd-utils     apg-st-databases        bluez5   rpm   valgrind  "
```

```
bitbake -e packagegroup-base-extended | grep ^RDEPENDS_packagegroup-base-extended=
```

returns

```
RDEPENDS_packagegroup-base-extended="    packagegroup-base     packagegroup-base-wifi     packagegroup-base-bluetooth               "
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `MACHINE` is dedicated to have one value which is the configuration file for your board, and you can not add bluetooth to it.

Yocto has an automatic bluetooth feature that handles adding bluetooth into your build. But it only there for boards that have a `builtin` bluetooth module.

For more info, check the machine features in the official Yocto doc [here](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/3.2.3/ref-manual/ref-features.html#machine-features).

Let me now explain how bluetooth is integrated:

Basically, you only need some kernel defconfig configuration and `bluez5` utility.

If you add the following line to `local.conf` or your custom machine file:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " bluetooth"
```

it will take effect if you build image that is based on `core-image` class, like `core-image-minimal`, because it contains a `packagegroup-base-bluetooth` as follows:

```
SUMMARY_packagegroup-base-bluetooth = "Bluetooth support"
RDEPENDS_packagegroup-base-bluetooth = "\
    bluez5 \
    "

RRECOMMENDS_packagegroup-base-bluetooth = "\
    kernel-module-bluetooth \
    kernel-module-l2cap \
    kernel-module-rfcomm \
    kernel-module-hci-vhci \
    kernel-module-bnep \
    kernel-module-hidp \
    kernel-module-hci-uart \
    kernel-module-sco \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('COMBINED_FEATURES', 'usbhost', 'kernel-module-hci-usb', '',d)} \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('COMBINED_FEATURES', 'pcmcia', 'kernel-module-bluetooth3c-cs', '',d)} \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('COMBINED_FEATURES', 'pcmcia', 'kernel-module-bluecard-cs', '',d)} \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('COMBINED_FEATURES', 'pcmcia', 'kernel-module-bluetoothuart-cs', '',d)} \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('COMBINED_FEATURES', 'pcmcia', 'kernel-module-dtl1-cs', '',d)} \
    "
```

It will add `packagegroup-base-bluetooth` only in two conditions:

1. If `bluetooth` in `DISTRO_FEATRUES` and not in `MACHINE_FEATURES` and one of (`pcmcia`, `pci` or `usbhost`) in `MACHINE_FEATURES`
2. If `bluetooth` in `COMBINED_FEATURES`.

For more info on `COMBINED_FEATURES` check this [link](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8.2/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-COMBINED_FEATURES).

So, you just need to make true one of the conditions.

You can dig in more to understand more details, check:

- `poky/meta/classes/core-image.bbclass`
- `poky/meta/recipes-core/packagegroups/packagegroup-base.bb`

**NOTE**

If your bluetooth module has a dedicated kernel driver for example, you need to activate it in the kernel configuration via a fragment file.

Or create a module recipe for it.

**EDIT**

In order to add bluetooth just:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " bluetooth"
```

after that, you can check that bluetooth package is added. Here are details:

`packagegroup-base-extended` is always added to images based on `core-image.bbclass` and here is its content:

```
RDEPENDS_packagegroup-base-extended = "\
    packagegroup-base \
    ${ADD_WIFI} \
    ${ADD_BT} \
    ${ADD_3G} \
    ${ADD_NFC} \
    "
```

You see the `ADD_BT` variable? It is by default empty, and it is filled with `packagegroup-base-bluetooth` only if the first condition is true, and here is the detail from the recipe:

```py
if "bluetooth" in distro_features and not "bluetooth" in machine_features and ("pcmcia" in machine_features or "pci" in machine_features or "usbhost" in machine_features):
        d.setVar("ADD_BT", "packagegroup-base-bluetooth")
```

Now, to check that it is added, run:

```
bitbake -e packagegroup-base | grep ^ADD_BT
```

you should see: `ADD_BT="packagegroup-base-bluetooth"`

Also, you can check that `packagegroup-base-extended` is added to your image:

```
bitbake -e <your_image> | grep ^IMAGE_INSTALL=
```

Also, you can check if `packagegroup-base-extended` has packaged bluetooth package with it:

```
bitbake -e packagegroup-base-extended | grep ^RDEPENDS_packagegroup-base-extended=
```

**EDIT2**:

Your configuration looks okay, specially when `packagegroup-base-bluetooth` is shipped with in `IMAGE_INSTALL`.

I have some comments that you need to consider anyways:

**local.conf**:

- Remove `bluez5` from `CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL`
- Change:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd bluetooth"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED += "sysvinit"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
VURTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = "systemd-compat-units"
```

with:

```
INIT_MANAGER = "systemd"
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " bluetooth"
```

- In your custom image file:

Put `inherit core-image` before `IMAGE_INSTALL`, because `IMAGE_INSTALL` of `core-image` will not take effect because it is `?=`. So:

```
inherit core-image
IMAGE_INSTALL += "\
    packagegroup-core-full-cmdline \    
    kernel-modules \
    libgpiod \
    ntp \
    sqlite3 \
    openssl \
    mtd-utils \
  "
```

Now, the only part that mention `bluetooth` is :

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " bluetooth"
```

Now, check again for the variable tests.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for replying to my question. This info really helps make things clearer for me. Does the automatic bluetooth feature include the bluetoothd deamon?  So if have bluetooth listed under DISTRO_FEATURES in my local.conf and usbhost in MACHINE_FEATURES (but not bluetooth) it will add the bluetooth package? I dont think my bluetooth module needs a dedicated kernel driver its connected to my SOM using ASCII on uart. Does that mean i wont need a kernel config fragment?

Comment: Check my EDIT, for bluetooth communication you just need to check the module's datasheet, and I think if it is ASCII via UART it wont need kernel fragments

Comment: hi, thank you for the additional information. Unfortunately I'm still having no luck getting this working. By the looks of it it doesn't even look like the kernel is trying to load the bluetooth module, running dmesg | grep blue doesn't return anything and I can't see anything that relates to bluetooth when the OS is booting up, clearly I am doing something very wrong.

Comment: Can you provide more information in the question? Provide your steps and Yocto layers you are using.

Comment: I've put additional details in the EDIT above.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. Taking onboard the feedback provided I'm managed to get to the point where the Bluetooth service at least starts now and bluetoothctl runs. Now I have work out why bluetoothctl is showing me No default controller available.

Once again thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not as simple as adding `bluetooth` as a DISTRO_FEATURE. Adding this only adds the `systemd` service and other user-space tools to the build. In fact, what you really need is your Linux kernel to support Bluetooth (i.e. add the necessary drivers and configuration to the Linux Kconfig). It can be done by means of enabling `CONFIG_BT` through `menuconfig` or directly on your config file. Additionally, you might want to include kernel drivers/plugins for the specific Bluetooth hardware you are using.

For `/sys/class/bluetooth` to exist, the kernel module `bluetooth.ko`, which is only autoloaded by systemd-udev if it actually finds a working Bluetooth hardware device.

I suggest you start by adding support for Bluetooth on your Linux kernel, recompiling and reflashing. Then all your user-space tools should start working if your BT hardware is able to be brought up.

This is a good resource that may help you: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bluetooth#Troubleshooting

Comment: thank you so much for your help. Taking onboard the feedback provided I'm managed to get to the point where the Bluetooth service at least starts now and bluetoothctl runs. Now I have work out why bluetoothctl is showing me No default controller available.

Once again thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Please vote/accept if it helped. This is again due to the BT HW not being detected. Have a look at `dmesg` output. You might be able to see what is going on there.

Comment: dmesg isn't giving me any error or problems  **root@sama5d27-som1-libra:~# dmesg | grep Blue
[    0.102021] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    0.102177] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    0.102213] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    0.102232] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    0.102280] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    0.930981] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    1.117100] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    1.120656] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    1.124538] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11**