# Bluetooth programming on embbedded linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, embedded, embedded-linux

I'm a newbie to embedded programming and trying to create a simple application that runs on a peripheral device. The application needs to advertise Bluetooth service with a specified UUID so other mobile phones can scan and pair with it. After that, the app on mobile phone can send some commands (via Bluetooth connection) to peripheral devices aims to start some interesting features.

To make things as simple as possible at the beginning, I integrated the library Bluez_inc which is built on top of Bluez and DBus, the app code is copied from `peripheral.c` in the sample folder of this library. Original link is: https://github.com/weliem/bluez_inc/blob/main/examples/peripheral/peripheral.c

I compiled the library & `peripheral.c` on Ubuntu 22.04 and the app works perfectly. it turns Bluetooth on and advertises new service, the test app on an Android phone can connect and send some information (by invoking the call back `on_local_char_write` function on the Linux side)

But when I compile and execute the app for the embedded system (with support of cross compiler), the app throws an exception:

```
2021-08-25 08:00:32:993 DEBUG [Adapter] failed to register advertisement (error 19: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Unknown method 'RegisterAdvertisement' or interface 'org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1'.)
2021-08-25 08:00:32:995 DEBUG [Adapter] failed to register application (error 19: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Unknown method 'RegisterApplication' or interface 'org.bluez.GattManager1'.)
```

Is this because Bluez is not available on Embbedded Linux?

Is there any library that is best fit here?

The peripheral device I'm working with is QCS404DK,

> # uname -a
>
> Linux nf-64 4.14.117-perf #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Aug 25 08:30:19 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

This is the source code that I want it to works on both Ubuntu and Embedded Linux:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include "adapter.h"
#include "device.h"
#include "logger.h"
#include "agent.h"
#include "application.h"
#include "advertisement.h"
#include "utility.h"
#include "parser.h"

#define TAG "Main"
#define HTS_SERVICE_UUID "00001809-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
#define TEMPERATURE_CHAR_UUID "00002a1c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
#define CUD_CHAR "00002901-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"

GMainLoop *loop = NULL;
Adapter *default_adapter = NULL;
Advertisement *advertisement = NULL;
Application *app = NULL;




void on_central_state_changed(Adapter *adapter, Device *device) {
    log_debug(TAG, "remote central %s is %s", binc_device_get_address(device), binc_device_get_connection_state_name(device));
    // ConnectionState state = binc_device_get_connection_state(device);
    // if (state == CONNECTED) {
    //     binc_adapter_stop_advertising(adapter, advertisement);
    // } else if (state == DISCONNECTED){
    //     binc_adapter_start_advertising(adapter, advertisement);
    // }
}

const char *on_local_char_read(const Application *application, const char *address, const char *service_uuid,
                        const char *char_uuid) {
    if (g_str_equal(service_uuid, HTS_SERVICE_UUID) && g_str_equal(char_uuid, TEMPERATURE_CHAR_UUID)) {
        const guint8 bytes[] = {0x06, 0x6f, 0x01, 0x00, 0xff, 0xe6, 0x07, 0x03, 0x03, 0x10, 0x04, 0x00, 0x01};
        GByteArray *byteArray = g_byte_array_sized_new(sizeof(bytes));
        g_byte_array_append(byteArray, bytes, sizeof(bytes));
        binc_application_set_char_value(application, service_uuid, char_uuid, byteArray);
        return NULL;
    }
    return BLUEZ_ERROR_REJECTED;
}

const char *on_local_char_write(const Application *application, const char *address, const char *service_uuid,
                          const char *char_uuid, GByteArray *byteArray) {
    log_debug(TAG, "On Char Write. UUID = %s", char_uuid);
    Parser *parser = parser_create(byteArray, LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    if(g_str_equal( char_uuid, TEMPERATURE_CHAR_UUID)){
        GString *settings = parser_get_string(parser);
        log_debug(TAG, "Settings = %s", settings->str);
        g_string_free(settings, TRUE);
    }else{
        log_debug(TAG, "Unknown Characteristic %s", char_uuid);
    }
    parser_free(parser);

    return NULL;
}

void on_local_char_start_notify(const Application *application, const char *service_uuid, const char *char_uuid) {
    log_debug(TAG, "on start notify");
    if (g_str_equal(service_uuid, HTS_SERVICE_UUID) && g_str_equal(char_uuid, TEMPERATURE_CHAR_UUID)) {
        const guint8 bytes[] = {0x06, 0x6A, 0x01, 0x00, 0xff, 0xe6, 0x07, 0x03, 0x03, 0x10, 0x04, 0x00, 0x01};
        GByteArray *byteArray = g_byte_array_sized_new(sizeof(bytes));
        g_byte_array_append(byteArray, bytes, sizeof(bytes));
        binc_application_notify(application, service_uuid, char_uuid, byteArray);
        g_byte_array_free(byteArray, TRUE);
    }
}

void on_local_char_stop_notify(const Application *application, const char *service_uuid, const char *char_uuid) {
    log_debug(TAG, "on stop notify");
}

gboolean callback(gpointer data) {
    if (app != NULL) {
        binc_adapter_unregister_application(default_adapter, app);
        binc_application_free(app);
        app = NULL;
    }

    if (advertisement != NULL) {
        binc_adapter_stop_advertising(default_adapter, advertisement);
        binc_advertisement_free(advertisement);
    }

    if (default_adapter != NULL) {
        binc_adapter_free(default_adapter);
        default_adapter = NULL;
    }

    g_main_loop_quit((GMainLoop *) data);
    return FALSE;
}
gboolean on_request_confirmation(Device *device) {
    log_debug(TAG, "requesting Confirmation for '%s", binc_device_get_name(device));
    return TRUE;
}


static void cleanup_handler(int signo) {
    if (signo == SIGINT) {
        log_error(TAG, "received SIGINT");
        callback(loop);
    }
}

void advertise_new_service() {
    binc_adapter_discoverable_on(default_adapter);
        

        log_debug(TAG, "Adapter name: %s", binc_adapter_get_name(default_adapter));

        // Setup remote central connection state callback
        binc_adapter_set_remote_central_cb(default_adapter, &on_central_state_changed);

        // Setup advertisement
        GPtrArray *adv_service_uuids = g_ptr_array_new();
        g_ptr_array_add(adv_service_uuids, HTS_SERVICE_UUID);

        advertisement = binc_advertisement_create();

        binc_advertisement_set_local_name(advertisement, "SleepHub Anywhere");
        binc_advertisement_set_services(advertisement, adv_service_uuids);
        g_ptr_array_free(adv_service_uuids, TRUE);
        binc_adapter_start_advertising(default_adapter, advertisement);

        Agent *agent = NULL;
        agent = binc_agent_create(default_adapter, "/org/bluez/BincAgent", DISPLAY_YES_NO);
        binc_agent_set_request_confirmation_cb(agent, &on_request_confirmation);

        // Start application
        app = binc_create_application(default_adapter);
        binc_application_add_service(app, HTS_SERVICE_UUID);
        binc_application_add_characteristic(
                app,
                HTS_SERVICE_UUID,
                TEMPERATURE_CHAR_UUID,
                GATT_CHR_PROP_READ | GATT_CHR_PROP_INDICATE | GATT_CHR_PROP_WRITE | GATT_CHR_PROP_NOTIFY);
        binc_application_add_descriptor(
                app,
                HTS_SERVICE_UUID,
                TEMPERATURE_CHAR_UUID,
                CUD_CHAR,
                GATT_CHR_PROP_READ | GATT_CHR_PROP_WRITE);

        const guint8 cud[] = "hello there";
        GByteArray *cudArray = g_byte_array_sized_new(sizeof(cud));
        g_byte_array_append(cudArray, cud, sizeof(cud));
        binc_application_set_desc_value(app, HTS_SERVICE_UUID, TEMPERATURE_CHAR_UUID, CUD_CHAR, cudArray);

        binc_application_set_char_read_cb(app, &on_local_char_read);
        binc_application_set_char_write_cb(app, &on_local_char_write);
        binc_application_set_char_start_notify_cb(app, &on_local_char_start_notify);
        binc_application_set_char_stop_notify_cb(app, &on_local_char_stop_notify);
        binc_adapter_register_application(default_adapter, app);
}
void on_powered_state_changed(Adapter *adapter, gboolean state) {
    log_debug(TAG, "powered '%s' (%s)", state ? "on" : "off", binc_adapter_get_path(adapter));
    if( state) {
        advertise_new_service();
    }
}
int main(void) {
    // Get a DBus connection
    GDBusConnection *dbusConnection = g_bus_get_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM, NULL, NULL);

    // Setup handler for CTRL+C
    if (signal(SIGINT, cleanup_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        log_error(TAG, "can't catch SIGINT");

    // Setup mainloop
    loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

    // Get the default default_adapter
    default_adapter = binc_adapter_get_default(dbusConnection);

    if (default_adapter != NULL) {
        log_debug(TAG, "using default_adapter '%s'", binc_adapter_get_path(default_adapter));

        // Make sure the adapter is on
        binc_adapter_set_powered_state_cb(default_adapter, &on_powered_state_changed);
        log_debug(TAG, "Power status = %d", binc_adapter_get_powered_state(default_adapter));
        if (!binc_adapter_get_powered_state(default_adapter)) {
            binc_adapter_power_on(default_adapter);
            log_debug(TAG, "Power on adapter %s", binc_adapter_get_path(default_adapter));
        } else {
            advertise_new_service();
        }
        
        
    } else {
        log_debug("MAIN", "No default_adapter found");
    }

    // Bail out after some time
    g_timeout_add_seconds(600, callback, loop);

    // Start the mainloop
    g_main_loop_run(loop);

    // Clean up mainloop
    g_main_loop_unref(loop);

    // Disconnect from DBus
    g_dbus_connection_close_sync(dbusConnection, NULL, NULL);
    g_object_unref(dbusConnection);
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: I would like to make it more clear that I can compile the app and execute it on embedded system, then get exception as described above.

Comment: `Is this because Bluez is not available on Embbedded Linux?` - Embedded Linux is just like any other kind of Linux, of course Bluez is available. Question is if you have installed it, and if the daemon is running (so it registers the relevant DBus methods)

Comment: hi @skandigraun, I think it's not installed yet within the firmware (or it's another version? there is system app called bt-app to control Bluetooth).
I tried `# bluetoothctl` but the command is not found
/bin/sh: bluetoothctl: not found

Comment: What prevents you from (cross-)compiling and installing it?

Comment: hi @skandigraun do you mean compiling and installing bluetoothctl? can you share more details about compiling and installing Bluez (or bluetoothctl)? 
I just updated my question to make it more clear that I can compile my app and execute it on the embedded system, then I got the exception as described above

Comment: You usually need a build to create customized Linux distributions for embedded systems and devices. These tools offer a way to build and configure a complete Linux system tailored to the specific requirements of your embedded hardware, and through them you can add packages. Examples include Buildroot and Yocto. So the first steps is to check what build system that is already used (if there are any) and then check how to add Bluetooth via this system.

Comment: Example of adding via Buildroot: https://tewarid.github.io/2014/10/24/customize-buildroot-to-build-bluez-tools.html and example of adding via Yocto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71515834/how-do-you-include-bluetooth-in-a-yocto-linux-system

Answer (score 0):

You ask about other libraries - this is one that does not use bluez/Dbus, and can set up a server with very little and much simpler code, just the two files below. This server will accept multiple simultaneous connections from phones, they will come through to le_callback as different clientnode numbers. But it has had limited testing on embedded systems, so it is a question of try it and see.

https://github.com/petzval/btferret

You need the following two files:

devices.txt

```
 ; Set ADDRESS = address of Pi
 ; Save this file as devices.txt
 ; semicolon is comment char
DEVICE = Embedded  TYPE=Mesh  NODE=1   ADDRESS = DC:A6:32:04:DB:56
  ; LE characteristics when acting as an LE server
  ; Specify UUIDs and let system allocate handles  
  PRIMARY_SERVICE = 1809
    LECHAR = Temperature  PERMIT=16 SIZE=16 UUID=2A1C   ; index 0  R/W/notify capable 
    LECHAR = CUD          PERMIT=16 SIZE=16 UUID=2901   ; index 1
```

server.c

```
/************************

DOWNLOAD from https://github.com/petzval/btferret
  btlib.c
  btlib.h
  
SAVE THIS FILE AS
  server.c  
  
COMPILE
  gcc server.c btlib.c -o server
  
RUN with devices.txt in same dir
  sudo ./server
  
*************************/   

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "btlib.h"

int le_callback(int clientnode,int operation,int cticn);

int main()
  {
  int n;
  unsigned char buf[16];

  if(init_blue("devices.txt") == 0)
    return(0);
     
  for(n = 0 ; n < 16 ; ++n)
    buf[n] = 0;
                                    // write to Temperature (index 0) 
  write_ctic(localnode(),0,buf,0);  // local device writes to its own
                                    // characteristic 
                                    // Size is known from devices.txt, so last
                                    // parameter (count) can be 0
                                    
  write_ctic(localnode(),1,buf,0);  // write to CUD (index 1) 

  le_server(le_callback,0);
                   // Become an LE server and wait for clients to connect.   
                   // when a client performs an operation such as connect, or
                   // write a characteristic, it calls the function le_callback()
                   // No timer          
  close_all();
  return(0);
  }


int le_callback(int clientnode,int operation,int cticn)
  {
  int n;
  unsigned char buf[16];
  
  if(operation == LE_CONNECT)
    {
    // clientnode has just connected
    }
  else if(operation == LE_READ)
    {
    // clientnode has just read local characteristic cticn
    }
  else if(operation == LE_WRITE)
    { 
      // clientnode has just written local characteristic cticn
    read_ctic(localnode(),cticn,buf,sizeof(buf));   // read characteristic to buf 
      // Temperature (index 0) is notify capable
      // so if the client has enabled notifications for this characteristic
      // the following write will send the data as a notification to the client
    for(n = 0 ; n < 16 ; ++n)
      buf[n] = 0;
    write_ctic(localnode(),0,buf,0);  
    } 
  else if(operation == LE_DISCONNECT)
    {
    // clientnode has just disconnected
    // uncomment next line to stop LE server when client disconnects
    // return(SERVER_EXIT);
    // otherwise LE server will continue and wait for another connection
    // or operation from other clients that are still connected
    }
  else if(operation == LE_TIMER)
    {
    // The server timer calls here every timerds deci-seconds     
    }
  
  return(SERVER_CONTINUE);
  }
```

Comment: This library supports Raspberry Pi but doesn't do for QCS404DK. Executed the `btferret` app on my board and it failed to control Bluez.